# How to apply one class to another?

Tags: css, w3c

So I have few elements in `.card` class and I want to apply `w3-card-4` class to it.

```
.card {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

}
.w3-card-4 > .card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no spaces in between

```
.card.w3-card-4{
    background-color:green;
}
```

`.w3-card-4 > .card` this is used when element of `class="card"` is direct child of element with `class="w3-card-4"`

For the html part. you have to include both classes in html too. like this:

```
<p class="card w3-card-4"> Text Here </p>
```

You don't have to include it in html if you are adding it through javascript / jQuery.